# jquery - finding elements by attributs

Tags: jquery

For example if I have html like this:

```
<div id="id">
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="class2" name="name1"></div>
    <div class="class2" name="name2"></div>
    <div class="class2" name="name3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have many divs with diffrent id values. It is possible to find and choose element by name attribute's value when having `<div id="id">` as a start point?

Comment: just a suggestion , if you are using one of them to query , why don't you make the other one dynamic , use id to query and class name as dynamic

Comment: I will think about that. Maybe You bring me a good idea but I need think about it a little of how to good implement it to my code and all project. Thanks.

Comment: Don't put `name` attributes on a `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, using the ["attribute equals"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector, e.g.:

```
$('#id div[name="foo"]').
```

will find all divs with `name="foo"` that are descendents (direct or otherwise) of the div with ID `id`.

Comment: I looks strage but i believe that it works and i will check this. Thanks.

Comment: But I have one more question here: what if i have 'id' as variable?

Comment: @Cris just use string concatenation to construct a suitable selector e.g. `$('#' + id + ' div[name="' + foo + '"]')`

Comment: I know concatenation of string but it is not as obvious as it seems to might be. Thanks at all. It give some light of what I can do in jQuery.

Comment: @Cris NB - in this one `foo` is now a variable, not the requested name itself.

Comment: Now the requested name is the name that 'foo' is part of, right?

Comment: @Cris the name contained in the variable called `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery selectors. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Something like this would give you one of your div elements.

`$('div[name=name1]')`

You can use this approach for other attributes as well. As the selector is merely a string, you can easily construct your selector from a block of javascript.

Comment: better to mark this as right answer (the green tick on left side) than saying thanks ;)

Comment: As 'thanks' I mark answer by clicking "^" sign. Green mark is when i can use answer directly in my own code :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also i think

```
$('div').attr('custom:attr')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an example how to directly select an tag by its parameter :

```
$('div[name=name1]').dosomething();
```

Should you want to add 'name' attribute next to 'id' after page loads use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('div#id').attr('name','name1');
});
```

Comment: But what if i have 'div' and 'name1' as variables?

Comment: Can you explain where this 'name1' will go then? Do you simply want to add another attribute next to 'id'?

Comment: It is more complicated than I show in this code. In this code I don't need to do enything more with 'name1'. I can't explain what I really need to do, because I will need to show all my code.